# git-commit vim-like syntax highlighting in emacs

Tags: git, vim, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I've recently picked up emacs as a general editor to replace gedit and vim. The one thing I miss *terribly* about vim is the git syntax highlighting. I have tried git-el, apparently with no luck.

The vim git-commit highlighting features a "subject line" highlight for the first fifty characters of the first line of the commit message, "error" highlights for the second line, comments, and red and green highlighting for added or removed files (which are themselves written in the precomposed comments.)

Is there a similarly functional syntax highlighting for emacs, and if so, how would I install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really do emacs but I did some quick searching and found [git-modes](https://github.com/lunaryorn/git-modes) and [magit](http://magit.github.com/magit/). I imagine that would get you started down the right road.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'd tried magit, but didn't really get into it. I might've failed to install it properly. I wasn't aware of git-modes.  It's just as good as vim's git-commit mode. Thank you!

Comment: Related to `git-commit-mode`, there are also `gitconfig-mode` and `gitignore-mode` packages which will syntax-colour `.git/config` an d your `.gitignore` files respectively.

Answer (score 3):

**2019 update:**

The answers presented here are 5 and 7 year old and it took me some time to figure out how to get various git highlightings without `magit`. Most links now lead to the magit repo and it is not particularly clear from there what the list of git-related packages currently is, nor whether they are on Melpa.

The [EmacsWiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GitCommitMode) does give the information, but with all the history of the movements of those various packages and their minor change of names, it is not totally easy to follow and see where things are now and what they are called.

So I thought that I would post a summary of these packages.

**They are all on Melpa** and any of these packages can be installed independently of the others, so you can pick and choose what you need.

- the package which allows syntax highlighting for commit messages is called `git-commit`
- for .gitignore highlighting, it is called `gitignore-mode`
- for .gitattributes, it is called `gitattributes-mode`
- and for .gitconfig, it is called `gitconfig-mode`

The package which answers the question is thus currently called `git-commit` and it is on Melpa.

Answer (score 0):

["Git Commit Mode" on EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GitCommitMode) has an overview of mainly historical interest.  The (presently somewhat argumentative) page seems to argue that you should use Magit.  All roads ultimately lead to [git-modes](https://github.com/magit/git-modes) which is allegedly now the default for Magit, too.

(My Ubuntu 14.04 `magit` does not seem to include it, still.  Installing `git-commit-mode` from [Marmalade](https://github.com/magit/git-modes#installation) quickly fixed that.)

A lot of random dot.emacs files in Google seem to include a `diff-mode` specification for `COMMIT_EDITMSG`.  I don't really see why -- the buffer does not contain a diff, and diff mode disables some useful text editing functions.  If you have nothing else out of the box, specifying `log-edit-mode` would make more sense.

Comment: The commit message will contain a diff of the changes to be commited if the verbose option is specified (`git commit --verbose` or an option in `.gitconfig`).